# Hourly tasks "randomly" fail

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Apache Airflow DAG which runs hourly but "randomly" fails, which means it succeeds about half of the time. The Dag consists of exactly one task which utilizes the BashOperator to do a single curl. The problem occurs with scheduled and manual triggers.

Airflow Version: 1.10.13.

Executor: Celery

Env: Kubernetes with Bitnami Airflow Helm Chart (1 Airflow-Web, 1 Airflow-Scheduler, 1 Airflow-Worker, I can give more information on this if it helps)

DB: PSQL

Redis: A Redis instance is provided to the Airflow setup but no keys are present.

DAGs: DAGs are defined inside a K8s ConfigMap and are updated regularily by Airflow

What have I tried:

- Dropped DB and set everything up from scratch two times
- Changed params like start_date, retries, etc.
- Monitored behaviour for 2 days

**Code**

```
  from builtins import range
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta

  from airflow.models import DAG
  from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

  args = {
      'owner': 'Airflow',
      'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 8, 8, 30, 0),
      'retries': 3,
      'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
  }

  dag = DAG(
      dag_id='persist__events_dag',
      default_args=args,
      schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
      tags=['SparkJobs']
  )

  run_job = BashOperator(
    task_id='curl_to_spark_api',
    bash_command="""
    //Here comes a curl command
    """,
    dag=dag,
  )
  
  run_job
```

**Logs**

From Airflow Worker on failed runs:

```
[2021-01-08 10:36:13,313: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[c6e3fdfb-5474-47aa-b333-be8c69b23ebe]
[2021-01-08 10:36:13,314: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Executing command in Celery: ['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']
[2021-01-08 10:36:19,279] {__init__.py:50} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2021-01-08 10:36:19,356] {dagbag.py:417} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py
/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1342: PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 538, in run
    dag = get_dag(args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 164, in get_dag
    'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: persist_events_dag. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
[2021-01-08 10:36:20,373: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] execute_command encountered a CalledProcessError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 78, in execute_command
    close_fds=True, env=env)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2021-01-08 10:36:20,373: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] None
[2021-01-08 10:36:20,526: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[c6e3fdfb-5474-47aa-b333-be8c69b23ebe] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 78, in execute_command
    close_fds=True, env=env)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 83, in execute_command
    raise AirflowException('Celery command failed')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed
[2021-01-08 10:36:43,230: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[8ba7956f-6b96-48f8-b112-3a4d7baa8bf7]
[2021-01-08 10:36:43,231: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Executing command in Celery: ['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T10:36:40.516529+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']
[2021-01-08 10:36:49,157] {__init__.py:50} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2021-01-08 10:36:49,158] {dagbag.py:417} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py
/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1342: PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 538, in run
    dag = get_dag(args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 164, in get_dag
    'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: persist_events_dag. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
[2021-01-08 10:36:50,560: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] execute_command encountered a CalledProcessError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 78, in execute_command
    close_fds=True, env=env)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T10:36:40.516529+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2021-01-08 10:36:50,561: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] None
[2021-01-08 10:36:50,649: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[8ba7956f-6b96-48f8-b112-3a4d7baa8bf7] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 78, in execute_command
    close_fds=True, env=env)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T10:36:40.516529+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 83, in execute_command
    raise AirflowException('Celery command failed')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed
[2021-01-08 10:37:23,414: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[10478bca-c21d-4cf5-b366-5ca1f66c0fe1]
[2021-01-08 10:37:23,415: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Executing command in Celery: ['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..data/persist_screenviews.py']
[2021-01-08 10:37:29,457] {__init__.py:50} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2021-01-08 10:37:29,458] {dagbag.py:417} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..data/persist_screenviews.py
Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: persist_events_dag.task_id 2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00 [queued]> airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
[2021-01-08 10:37:36,294: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[10478bca-c21d-4cf5-b366-5ca1f66c0fe1] succeeded in 12.8788606680464s: None
```

If a run **succeeds**, I nevertheless get the following error in the logs of the Airflow scheduler:

```
Process DagFileProcessor144631-Process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (dag_id)=(persist_events_dag) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 159, in _run_file_processor
    pickle_dags)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1609, in process_file
    dag.sync_to_db()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1535, in sync_to_db
    orm_dag.tags = self.get_dagtags(session=session)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1574, in get_dagtags
    session.commit()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2536, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2678, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2638, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1083, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (dag_id)=(persist_events_dag) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO dag (dag_id, root_dag_id, is_paused, is_subdag, is_active, last_scheduler_run, last_pickled, last_expired, scheduler_lock, pickle_id, fileloc, owners, description, default_view, schedule_interval) VALUES (%(dag_id)s, %(root_dag_id)s, %(is_paused)s, %(is_subdag)s, %(is_active)s, %(last_scheduler_run)s, %(last_pickled)s, %(last_expired)s, %(scheduler_lock)s, %(pickle_id)s, %(fileloc)s, %(owners)s, %(description)s, %(default_view)s, %(schedule_interval)s)]
[parameters: {'dag_id': 'persist_events_dag', 'root_dag_id': None, 'is_paused': True, 'is_subdag': False, 'is_active': True, 'last_scheduler_run': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 10, 55, 4, 297819, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 'last_pickled': None, 'last_expired': None, 'scheduler_lock': None, 'pickle_id': None, 'fileloc': '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py', 'owners': 'Airflow', 'description': None, 'default_view': None, 'schedule_interval': '"0 * * * *"'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
Process DagFileProcessor144689-Process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (dag_id)=(persist_events_dag) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 159, in _run_file_processor
    pickle_dags)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1609, in process_file
    dag.sync_to_db()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1535, in sync_to_db
    orm_dag.tags = self.get_dagtags(session=session)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1574, in get_dagtags
    session.commit()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2536, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2678, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2638, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1083, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dag_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (dag_id)=(persist_events_dag) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO dag (dag_id, root_dag_id, is_paused, is_subdag, is_active, last_scheduler_run, last_pickled, last_expired, scheduler_lock, pickle_id, fileloc, owners, description, default_view, schedule_interval) VALUES (%(dag_id)s, %(root_dag_id)s, %(is_paused)s, %(is_subdag)s, %(is_active)s, %(last_scheduler_run)s, %(last_pickled)s, %(last_expired)s, %(scheduler_lock)s, %(pickle_id)s, %(fileloc)s, %(owners)s, %(description)s, %(default_view)s, %(schedule_interval)s)]
[parameters: {'dag_id': 'persist_events_dag', 'root_dag_id': None, 'is_paused': True, 'is_subdag': False, 'is_active': True, 'last_scheduler_run': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 10, 55, 33, 439514, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 'last_pickled': None, 'last_expired': None, 'scheduler_lock': None, 'pickle_id': None, 'fileloc': '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/..2021_01_08_10_33_28.059622242/persist_screenviews.py', 'owners': 'Airflow', 'description': None, 'default_view': None, 'schedule_interval': '"0 * * * *"'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,392] {scheduler_job.py:963} INFO - 1 tasks up for execution:
    <TaskInstance: persist_events_dag.task_id 2021-01-08 09:00:00+00:00 [scheduled]>
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,402] {scheduler_job.py:997} INFO - Figuring out tasks to run in Pool(name=default_pool) with 128 open slots and 1 task instances ready to be queued
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,403] {scheduler_job.py:1025} INFO - DAG persist_events_dag has 0/16 running and queued tasks
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,407] {scheduler_job.py:1085} INFO - Setting the following tasks to queued state:
    <TaskInstance: persist_events_dag.task_id 2021-01-08 09:00:00+00:00 [scheduled]>
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,420] {scheduler_job.py:1159} INFO - Setting the following 1 tasks to queued state:
    <TaskInstance: persist_events_dag.task_id 2021-01-08 09:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,420] {scheduler_job.py:1195} INFO - Sending ('persist_events_dag', 'task_id', datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 9, 0, tzinfo=<TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>), 1) to executor with priority 1 and queue default
[2021-01-08 10:57:22,424] {base_executor.py:58} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'run', 'persist_events_dag', 'task_id', '2021-01-08T09:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/external/persist_screenviews.py']
[2021-01-08 10:57:36,579] {scheduler_job.py:1334} INFO - Executor reports execution of persist_events_dag.task_id execution_date=2021-01-08 09:00:00+00:00 exited with status success for try_number 1
```

Comment: It is interesting that the dag_id in the code is "persist__events_dag" with 2 underscore, but in the log it is "persist_events_dag"

Comment: I would change a couple of things: schedule_interval='@hourly', start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 8), catchup=False, max_active_runs=1. Args: 'retries': 1